# python - How to count the number of occurances of sub-string in a list

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, list, count

if I have a list like

```
list = ['helloA', 'hiA', 'helloB', helloC']
```

I would like to count the number of sub-string `'hello'` occurances in that list.

**Edit**:

Actually I already had a ways to count it like this code below:

```
numb = [x for x,y in enumerate(data['column']) if 'sub-string' in y]
print len(numb)
```

I just want to know if there is any other way or better way to do it.
Thank you

Comment: How are you counting substrings? Would `['hellohello']` have 1 or 2? Would `['hel', 'lo']` have 1 or 0?

Comment: what have you tried? Please read [those suggestions on how to write a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Artyer `['hellohello']` would be counted as 1. I mean to count the number of string that contain the sub-string in the list.

Comment: @FrancescoMontesano okay, sorry. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
['hello' in x for x in list].count(True)
```

or

```
sum(['hello' in x for x in list ])
```

or

```
len([1 for x in list if 'hello' in x])
```

or

```
''.join(list).count('hello')
```

NOTE: the last method may provide a different count from the first three methods if some of your strings contain 'hello' substring multiple times - see the comment by @Artyer to your original question.

Also, avoid calling a list name 'list' ( a built-in type in Python).

Answer (score 1):

You can sum a list of boolean checks against each string using:

```
my_list = ['helloA', 'hiA', 'helloB', 'helloC']
sum('hello' in x for x in my_list)
```

Also, try not to use `list` as a variable name, as it is a built-in function/object in Python.

Comment: Python reserved words, aka keywords, cannot be used as variable names. You probably want to say that `list` is a built-in

Comment: @Anton, Of course one can use built-in type names as variable name. However, just because Python allows it - it does not mean this should be done.

Answer (score 1):

A simple example

```
count = 0
string = "hello"
for i in list:
    if string in i:
        count += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sum()` and the `in` operator to add up the number of times a string with the substring `hello` appears in the list:

```
>>> lst = ['helloA', 'hiA', 'helloB', 'helloC']
>>> sum(string.count('hello') for string in lst)
3
>>>
```